# Can angular-ui-grid be used with angular material design?

Tags: material-design, angular-ui-grid, angular-material

The title pretty much says it all: Can angular [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) be used with [angular material design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) in a way that follows the material design principles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can, but only at a look and feel level.  Basically most of the visual elements in ui-grid are over-rideable with templates (`cellTemplate`, `rowTemplate` etc).  You can also override a lot of the css.  So if you're prepared to work through it there's no reason why most of it cannot be tailored.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the customize style option on the ui-grid site does not give you the ability to change most of the classes that you will eventually need to in order to make it conform to the material design spec.  Additionally it lacks responsive features or the ability to create the kinds of animations/transitions that are a signature of material design.

I really like both projects, its just hard to try and build an app on two frameworks that are currently under active development.  I am using ui-grid in my Angular-Material app, but I don't think I would if I had to do it over again

Comment: if not ui-grid, what would you use ? We are about to use a grid in our material project ...

Comment: It depends on how many advanced features you need (filtering, grouping,  etc.)  Md-data-table (https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) looks promising, but it does not have many of ui-grid's advanced features.  I also have not used md-data-table in an actual project yet, so I can't speak to how well it holds up in production.